# Getting a nil value from Firebase using Swift

Tags: json, swift, database, firebase

I've tried this for five days now, but no luck.

Here is my Firebase snapshot:

```
Snap (Channels) {
    HiruFM =     {
        image = "hiru_fm_logo.png";
        title = "Hiru FM";
    };
    SirasaFM =     {
        image = "sirasa_fm_logo.png";
        title = SirasaFM;
    };
}
```

Below is what I tried:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference().child("Channels")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap) in
        print(snap) // checking if the snap grabs the data (confirmed)
        guard var data = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> else {return}


        let channeTitle = data["title"] as? String ?? "No title"
        print(channeTitle) // prints "No title" (this is the problem)

        let channelImage = data["image"] as? String ?? "No image"
        print(channelImage) // prints "No image"
        let myData = Channels(title: channeTitle, image: channelImage)
        self.channels.append(myData)
    }
}
```

Comment: What keys do exist in `data`?

Comment: Only String values

Comment: That's not what I asked. You are trying to access the keys "title" and "image" but they don't seem to exist. What actual keys do exist?

Comment: it's in the Channels > sub category's. I can drill down specifically in to those category's, but what if I have 100 of category'S   

Snap (Channels) {
    HiruFM =     {
        image = "hiru_fm_logo.png";
        title = "Hiru FM";
    };
    SirasaFM =     {
        image = "sirasa_fm_logo.png";
        title = SirasaFM;
    };
}

Comment: There's your problem. You have a dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: @GayanChanaka, can you print and mention, what `snap.value` is??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to understand the difference between reading a node by .value and .childAdded, and another consideration is disassociating parent node keys from the data it contains.

Start with the following structure

```
channels
  chan_0
    image: "hiru_fm_logo.png"
    name: "HiruFM"
    title "Hiru FM"
  chan_1
    image: "sirasa_fm_logo.png"
    name: "SirasaFM"
    title "Sirasa FM"
```

chan_0, chan_1 etc keys are created with childbyAutoId and allows separation of keys from child data. That way if one of the child values change, it keeps integrity between the parent node and other nodes that reference it. In practice if HiruFM becomes HiruXM, all that needs to be done is change the child node, not the parent.

Then a structure to hold you data. Note that the structure *init* breaks down the snapshot and assigns the properties

```
struct ChannelStruct{
    var image = ""
    var title = ""
    var name = ""

    init(aSnap: DataSnapshot) {
        let dict = aSnap.value as! [String: Any]

        if let image = dict["image"] as? String {
            self.image = image
        }

        if let title = dict["title"] as? String {
            self.title = title
        }

        if let name = dict["name"] as? String {
            self.name = name
        }
    }
}
```

and an class array to hold the structures

```
var channels = [ChannelStruct]()
```

and then finally the code to read in the node and iterate over the child nodes to add them to the array

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child("channels")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let aChannel = ChannelStruct(aSnap: snap)
            self.channels.append(aChannel)
        }
    } else {
        print("no channels found")
    }
}
```

Note that when reading by .value, the parent node, *channels*, ALL of the child nodes are read in, so they need to be iterated to get each child - this also maintains their order. Whereas, if we use .childAdded, it presents each child node, one at a time, so no iteration is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try it

```
for imageData in data
{
    let item:NSDictionary = imageData as NSDictionary
    let channeTitle = data["title"] as? String ?? "No title"
    print(channeTitle)
    let channelImage = data["image"] as? String ?? "No image"
    print(channelImage) 
    let myData = Channels(title: channeTitle, image: channelImage)
    self.channels.append(myData)
}
```

Here if you need to fetch data of dictionary of dictionary first you need fetch each data and then their child node data in loop.

Comment: Thank you, 

let item:NSDictionary = imageData as NSDictionary
this gave me an error. saying (Cannot convert value of type '(key: String, value: Any)' to type 'NSDictionary' in coercion)

Comment: Do not use `NSDictionary` in Swift. Use a Swift dictionary.